# How do you parse values from a txt file into a list of records in OCaml?

Tags: list, parsing, ocaml, record

I'm trying to learn OCaml and am having difficulty with parsing a file into a list of records. Let's say I have a text file with the following format:

Jim Bob, red 
Steve Black, blue

etc..

I would like to be able to parse the csv's into a list of records which I would then later use to do basic list operations such as sorting, with the record being:

```
type person_info =
{
  name : string;
  favorite_color  : string;
}
```

I have the parse function:

```
let parse_csv =
  let regexp = Str.regexp (String.concat "\\|" [
                             "\"\\([^\"\\\\]*\\(\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*\\)*\\)\",?";
                             "\\([^,]+\\),?";
                             ",";
                           ]) in
  fun text ->
    let rec loop start result =
      if Str.string_match regexp text start then
        let result =
          (try Str.matched_group 1 text with Not_found ->
             try Str.matched_group 3 text with Not_found ->
               "") :: result in
        loop (Str.match_end ()) result
      else
        result in
    List.rev ((if
                 try String.rindex text ',' = String.length text - 1
                 with Not_found -> false
               then [""] else [])
              @ loop 0 [])
```

That will split everything up for me. However I have no idea how to read things into a list of records and I can't even get it to parse properly into an array:

```
let () =
  let ic = open_in Sys.argv.(1) in
  let lines = ref [] in
  try
    while true do

    lines := Array.of_list (parse_csv (input_line ic))

    done
  with End_of_file ->
    close_in ic
```

This will work fine without calling parse_csv, but fails when I try to parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that there [exists a CSV module](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-csv) that you can install with `opam install csv`.  You can then easily read the file (in the interactive toploop):

```
# #require "csv";;
/home/chris/.opam/system/lib/csv: added to search path
/home/chris/.opam/system/lib/csv/csv.cma: loaded
# let c = Csv.load "data.csv";;
val c : Csv.t = [["Jim Bob"; "red"]; ["Steve Black"; "blue"]]
```

You can then easily convert it to your favorite format:

```
# let read_people fname =
  Csv.load fname
  |> List.map (function [name; favorite_color] -> {name; favorite_color }
                      | _ -> failwith "read_people: incorrect file");;
val read_people : string -> person_info list = <fun>
# read_people "data.csv";;
- : person_info list =
[{name = "Jim Bob"; favorite_color = "red"};
 {name = "Steve Black"; favorite_color = "blue"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start your script on a *nix system like this - good for testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ocaml
#use "topfind";;
#require "str";;
```

Then test your script. The error message says

```
File "./so_howdoyouparse.ml", line 37, characters 13-54:
Error: This expression has type string array
       but an expression was expected of type 'a list
```

Include the error message in your question next time.

And yes, indeed, why are you trying to assign Array.of_list to a reference initialized with an empty list? This line could read:

```
lines := (parse_csv (input_line ic)) :: !lines
```

Then you have got *something* working. With my edits (return the contents of lines) I am getting:

```
val myresult : string list list =
  [["Steve Black"; " blue"]; ["Jim Bob"; " red"]]
```

You just forgot to use your person_info record.

Your code still has a lot of issues, it is convoluted, this answer aims at helping you getting your code to run, then test and improve it.